# Übersetzung von "What does this stand for"

Tags: preposition

Zum Beispiel: ich bin auf der Strasse und sehe eine Abkürzung, die ich nicht erkenne. Also fragte ich meinen Freund.

1. Wofür steht SBB? (What does SBB stand for?)
2. Was ist SBB Abkürzung für? (What is SBB the shortform for?)
3. Wofür ist SBB Abkürzung? (What is SBB the shortform for?)

Welche Ausdrücke sind richtiger, und welcher ist ganz falsch?

Comment: Im Allgemeinem suche ich für "xyz abkürzung". en/de.wikipedia.org/wiki/xyz kann auch nützlich sein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variante 1) ist die korrekte Art, nach der Bedeutung einer Abkürzung zu fragen.

2) ist eine wörtliche Übersetzung aus dem englischen und daher im Deutschen grammatikalisch falsch. Man würde dich in den meisten Fällen aber trotzdem verstehen.

Wenn du 3) um "die" ergänzt zu "Wofür ist SBB die Abkürzung?", wäre das auch OK. Es klingt etwas umständlich und man merkt den englischen Ursprung der Formulierung deutlich, aber es ist sprachlich korrekt.

Ich würde als Alternative zu 1) noch "Was bedeutet (die Abkürzung) SBB?" empfehlen, das ist dann etwas freier übersetzt und ist im Deutschen auch durchaus geläufig.